# Autofill method of range class failed - help needed for my code

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to make this work. It worked fine on my x64 version of office but not the x86 on my colleagues' computers. Can anyone gimme a fix please?

The VBA engine highlighted `Range("AV5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AV5:AV" & NoOfClients)` as the cause

```
Private Sub Check_Cases_Click()
Dim NoOfClients As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
CO_Select = Application.InputBox("Please input the name of caseworker you would like to check on.", "Caseworker Name")
Range("A2").value = CO_Select


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
NoOfClients = Range("C2").value
CO_Name = Range("A2").value



CheckCaseMsg = MsgBox(CO_Name & ", there are " & NoOfClients & " clients under your name." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "System will now calculate all your active cases and display " & vbNewLine & _
                    "all the clients for your information." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Confirm?", vbYesNo, "Case Checking")

If CheckCaseMsg = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
End If


If CheckCaseMsg = vbYes Then

'Remove the filters if one exists
'=========================================
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
Selection.AutoFilter
End If

Clear
Startup_Formula

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Range("AV5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AV5:AV" & NoOfClients)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Range("GI_Table[[#All],[Client number]]").Copy
Range("GI_Table[[#All],[Client number]]").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("GI_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        Array("ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "RENEWED"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

GI_CustomSort
GI_CustomSort


MsgBox "Case Checking Ready", vbInformation, "Ready"
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be Fill Down action, I guess it can be a copy n times (n= NoOfClients). The formula as I assigned as Startup_Formula is a sub, containing an array formula `Sub Startup_Formula()
Sheets("Grand Info Sheet").Range("AV5").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Table_MIS[CLIENTNUM],SMALL(IF($A$2=Table_MIS[CASEWORKER]," & _
                            "ROW(Table_MIS[CASEWORKER])-MIN(ROW(Table_MIS[CASEWORKER]))+1,""""),ROW(AV5))),"""")"
End Sub`

Comment: Basically I need to use the array formula and fill it down a number of times according to my detected NoOfClients in a table....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I know what's the problem now, I think.

I limited my scroll area in the Sub for Worksheet_Activate and the value of NoOfClients exceeded the allowed amount!

So I deleted that and I think it's ok now! This is my final code (with the scroll area becoming dynamic now)

```
Private Sub Check_Cases_Click()
Dim NoOfClients As Long

ActiveSheet.ScrollArea = ""
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
CO_Select = Application.InputBox("Please input the name of caseworker you would like to check on.", "Caseworker Name")
Range("A2").value = CO_Select


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
NoOfClients = Range("C2").value
CO_Name = Range("A2").value



CheckCaseMsg = MsgBox(CO_Name & ", there are " & NoOfClients & " clients under your name." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "System will now calculate all your active cases and display " & vbNewLine & _
                    "all the clients for your information." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Confirm?", vbYesNo, "Case Checking")

If CheckCaseMsg = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
End If


If CheckCaseMsg = vbYes Then

'Remove the filters if one exists
'=========================================
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
Selection.AutoFilter
End If

Clear
Startup_Formula


'Fill down the formula for n times where n= No of Clients of the Caseworker'
'=============================================================================
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set Sht = Worksheets("Grand Info Sheet")
NoOfClients = Range("C2").value
NoOfClientsAdjusted = NoOfClients + 4

Sht.Range("AV5").AutoFill Destination:=Sht.Range("AV5:AV" & NoOfClientsAdjusted)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Range("GI_Table[[#All],[Client number]]").Copy
Range("GI_Table[[#All],[Client number]]").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

GI_CustomSort

MsgBox "Case Checking Ready", vbInformation, "Ready"
Range("A1").Select
End If

ActiveSheet.ScrollArea = "A1:AW" & NoOfClientsAdjusted + 5
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just `Range("..").` you should try

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Name")

sht.Range("..")
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you mean I should do 'sht.Range("AV5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AV5:AV" & NoOfClients)'

Comment: `sht.Range("AV5").AutoFill Destination:= sht.Range("AV5:AV" & NoOfClients)` you missed one but yeah try it

Answer (score 0):

You will get the `Autofill method of range class failed` error if the value of `NoOfClients` is `5`. The end row is the same as the start row. Here is a simple way to reproduce the error.

```
Sub Sample()
    NoOfClients = 5

    Range("AV5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AV5:AV" & NoOfClients)
End Sub
```

An alternative to `.Autofill` is to directly write to the range. For ex:

```
Range("AV5:AV" & NoOfClients).Formula = Range("AV5").Formula
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But usually, my NoOfClients is like 200+. I don't really experience any test scenario where my NoOfClients become 5.

Comment: Basically, the reason why I set this is because the array formula I use is in AV5 (the first row of the table). I want to fill down a number of times (according to the number called by NoOfClients (usually 100-200))

Comment: Did you try the alternative?

Comment: I did. It says Application-defined or object-defined error. Maybe I need to declare something....?

Comment: Can you post the new code that you tried based on my comment?